# Where can I find transactions per second statistics?

Tags: transactions, explorers, statistics, graphs

A few days ago Vitalik [claimed](https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin/status/695989627249782784) Ethereum was doing 8 transactions per second. The tweet linked to [Etherchain](https://etherchain.org), which doesn't seem to have a transactions per second graph.

Where can I find an Ethereum transactions per second graph over time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many transactions can the network handle?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/how-many-transactions-can-the-network-handle)

Comment: On the olympic testnet there were already a peak of 25 tx/sec. Frontier and Homestead should be able to run even more. See the answer linked above.

Comment: on the etherchain stats page, look for the `TPS` graph at the bottom.

Comment: Ethereum TPS is, on average, 1.3 right now.   There have been spikes to 8TPS, but that was an attack, and to be honest, the network couldn't handle it.   Sharding will fix this.

Comment: If you want to get an idea of the current TPS across different blockchains or networks take a look at https://realtps.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[etherchain.org](https://etherchain.org/statistics/basic) now shows a chart of the average number of transactions per second during a given day. At the time of writing the peak was on the 6th of February 2016 with a 1.2 average transactions per second during the day.

The indicator is calculated by dividing the total number of transactions on a given day by the number of seconds in a day (86400).

Answer (score 0):

There's a really [neat page at Amberdata.io](https://amberdata.io/dashboards/transactions) that displays the number of transactions per second, as well as, a lot of other useful transactions statistics.

Here's a graph taken from their website:

[image]

As you can see it shows the current and average number of transactions per second as well as the a historical view with the following timeframes: `6h 3d 7d 30d 6m 1y all`.

Let me know if that's helpful!