# How to find transactions per minute

Tags: transactions, web3js

I am trying to find the number of transactions in the Ethereum network using web3. I couldn't find any web3 functions to get the same.

I could see **etherchain.org** and some other network browsers have implemented the same. I tried to dig into their codes and found nothing useful. Found another thread on the same topic [Where can I find transactions per second statistics?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/where-can-i-find-transactions-per-second-statistics) saying divide the number of transactions per day and the number of seconds per day, but wondering how to find the number of transactions per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the daily transaction from http://etherscan.io/chart/tx . Right mouse click and view source, and you will find the following type of data:

```
data: [ {y : 8893, dt : 'Thursday, July 30, 2015', difficulty : '0.121 TH', estHashrate : '23.7569 GH', blockTime : '4', blockSize : '644', blockCount : '6912', unclesCount : '1299', newaddress : '9205'  },
...
,{y : 42581, dt : 'Sunday, June 12, 2016', difficulty : '47.368 TH', estHashrate : '3454.4512 GH', blockTime : '14', blockSize : '1463', blockCount : '6064', unclesCount : '468', newaddress : '2117'  },
    ]
```

42,581 is the number of transactions for Sunday June 12, 2016.

If you want to try and find the transactions in each block, you can use this script in [Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3478#3478) .

You will see in the script that to find a block, use

```
var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
```

And to find the list of transactions in the block, use

```
if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
  block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
    if (myaccount == "*" || myaccount == e.from || myaccount == e.to) {
      console.log("  tx hash          : " + e.hash + "\n"
        + "   nonce           : " + e.nonce + "\n"
        + "   blockHash       : " + e.blockHash + "\n"
        + "   blockNumber     : " + e.blockNumber + "\n"
        + "   transactionIndex: " + e.transactionIndex + "\n"
        + "   from            : " + e.from + "\n" 
        + "   to              : " + e.to + "\n"
        + "   value           : " + e.value + "\n"
        + "   gasPrice        : " + e.gasPrice + "\n"
        + "   gas             : " + e.gas + "\n"
        + "   input           : " + e.input);
    }
  })
}
```

The block timestamp will be in:

```
block.timestamp
```

Here's some sample `geth` JavaScript code to get your data:

```
> var i;
undefined
> for (i = 1696781; i < 1696785; i++) {
.. var block = eth.getBlock(i);
.. if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
...... console.log(i + " " + block.timestamp + " " + block.transactions.length);
...... }
.. }
1696781 1465823661 6
1696782 1465823697 8
1696783 1465823704 5
1696784 1465823718 7
undefined
```

The block.timestamp field is a Unix timestamp, so 1465823718 = GMT: Mon, 13 Jun 2016 13:25:16 GMT.

You can also try using the [JavaScript API - web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblocktransactioncount) function:

```
> var i;
undefined
> for (i = 1696781; i < 1696785; i++) {
.. var block = eth.getBlock(i);
.. var txcount = eth.getBlockTransactionCount(i);
.. console.log(i + " " + block.timestamp + " " + txcount);
.. }
1696781 1465823661 6
1696782 1465823697 8
1696783 1465823704 5
1696784 1465823718 7
undefined
```