# How do I compare the "scalability" capabilities between ethereum and bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, scalability

I'm trying to assess how they can be compared.  Bitcoin can process 7 trans/sec, is there some equivalent on the Ethereum side?  How should I think about this and what quantitative info should I use?

Answer (score 9):

Let me try to explain.

### Bitcoin Block Size Limit

The **Bitcoin** side is pretty simple to understand. The bitcoin blockchain has a hardcoded **block size limit** of 1 MiB. With an average transaction size of around 600 B and a target block time of 10 minutes, you get

```
1024 * 1024 / 600 B = 1747.7 transactions per block,
```

which translates down to

```
1747.7 / 600 s = 2.9127 transactions per second.
```

Here we are at around 3 transactions per second in practice, however, if you reduce the average transaction size, it's possible *in theory* to reach higher rates, maybe 7 transactions per second? That said, there is nothing that scales in Bitcoin unless the network finds consensus on a solution to increase the blocksize or any other scalability fix.

### Ethereum Block Gas Limit

**Ethereum** introduces a new concept which has no transaction or block size limit but a gas limit. Gas is a unit which basicly calculates fee costs. Every transaction, every contract execution and every data storage operation on the blockchain costs gas. Every block has a **block gas limit** of default 4,712,388 gas which can be spent on every block.

Let's assume an average transaction size of 21,000 gas per transaction which is required for a default value transfer and a target block time of 15 seconds, we have by default the following:

```
4712388 / 21000 = 224.4 transactions per block
```

which translates down to

```
224.4 / 15 = 14.96 transactions per second.
```

So, at the current level of gas block limit and block time, there is a default possible throughput of 15 transactions per second. If you increase the required gas per transaction, it's probably a little bit lower.

But since you asked about scalability, the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) specifies in equations 44-46 how the block gas limit scales:

[image: yellow paper screenshot]

Which basicly means the block gas limit can increase by `1+1/1024` each block, or:

```
(1+1/1024)^5760 = 276.51227240329152144804
```

which is a scalability factor for 276 per day. Ethereum scales indefinitely. *In theory*, in practice, the early olympic testnet was able to stress the network to levels at around [25 transactions per second](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1034/87). And this is only the status quo. See also this post about [transaction size](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1106/87).